# package net.java.stun4j does not exist

Tags: java

I am trying to create a sip protocol handler. I am facing some difficulties to create this. I am trying to use stun4j but i can not import it. Whenever I import it shows an error package java.net.stun4j does not exist.

```
import net.java.stun4j.StunAddress;
import net.java.stun4j.client.NetworkConfigurationDiscoveryProcess;
import net.java.stun4j.client.StunDiscoveryReport;
```

I have tried different library jar files but it is always showing error. I have used java sip api. But import is always showing error. If I have to get rid of this error, what jar file should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put jar files to your classpath.

Comment: yes , i have included stun4j-1.0.MOBICENTS.jar. It is showing error. I am not understanding what jar file i should  use.

Comment: @user2982384 are you doing it so -classpath lib/*.jar or -classpath lib/stun4j-1.0.MOBICENTS.jar ? :)